# inserting variable into database with php

Tags: php, mysql, function, object

I'm editing part of a user login system and I'm very confused on one issue. I'm trying to allow the user to change their username using their email as a reference for the lookup. For some reason I can't get the $email variable to set properly. When I change the variable $email to an address that I know is in my database (meaning I remove $email and change it to an address that exists) the username is properly changed. When I swap it back to $email, nothing happens.

The strange part is when I echo $email, the correct email address is displayed. I can't figure out why it won't let me do this despite it being echoed properly. Is it possible to not be a string despite an email address being displayed?

I understand about sql injections. I'm just trying to keep the code as simple as possible for now so I can get the functionality working first.

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $user->get_email($username);
    $newuser = $_POST['newusername'];
    $server = 'localhost';
    $usern = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $usern, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(testdb, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($username)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$newuser' WHERE email = '$email'") or    die(mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

Also, when I change the query statement so that the reference value is the userid, the username is correctly inserted. From this I know that $email isn't being set properly.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$newuser' WHERE userid = '$userid'") or    die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `id` field in the `WHERE`? It's not only easier, it's also safer and faster.

Comment: SQL injection all over the place here! Please please please sanitize your inputs!

Comment: That's what I am going to do. I just want to figure out why email won't work. It's really bugging me and it might help me in the future.

Comment: @user1104854 Hi again. Please do not re-ask a question on Stack Overflow. It is likely to be closed as a duplicate. Instead, edit your earlier question to clarify it. Doing so will move it into the active questions and it will get seen by others again.

Comment: Michael, I tried to delete that post but instead I had to flag it and ask for a moderator to delete it. I figured out part of that issue, but I felt like adding more would just lead to more confusion and less chance of finding the cause.

Comment: When you're echoing the `$email` variable, have you tried doing it inside your `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` block?

Comment: Yes, that's where I tried to echo it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($username)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$newuser' WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Where in your code are you setting the `$username` variable?  If it's not set, your update won't run.  You should probably go back and review your variable names and make sure they're consistent (and set) throughout the rest of the page.

Comment: I didn't notice that, but changing it to $newuser still didn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your get_email() function is returning a bad address. 
Are you sure your authentication system is working fine in all other ways?

What happens when you do this:

```
echo "UPDATE users SET username='$newuser' WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Also, you will want to sanitize your input for $newuser to avoid SQL injection. Like one of the comments said, you should be using the user id instead of email. I am not sure what authentication class you are using, but you should be able to find something like $user->returnID() and update using that.

Comment: I understand and I am going to use userid for a reference. I originally had it like this and realized that I should be using ID, now I'm just annoyed that I can't figure out why I can't use email.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway it's recommend to add

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
```

Maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I should use the following:

```
<?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $email = $user->get_email($username); // where does $username come from anyway? and where are you initiating the $user object?
    $newuser = $_POST['newusername'];
    $server = 'localhost';
    $usern = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $usern, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(testdb, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($newuser)) {
        $newuser = mysql_real_escape_string($newuser);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='" . $newuser . "' WHERE email = '". $email ."'") or    die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

The mysql_real_escape_string() creates a new string. It will escape characters which probably can damage your database when they are putted in. (Called: SQL Injection)

For examples of SQL Injection to give you an idea what it is, and how it can be used and protected:
http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html